# Reading Video frame by frame in Python using code in Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, video

I am trying to translate the following piece of code that is suppose to read a video frame by frame and than compute the difference between the frames, my translation didn't seem to work so well since I am getting different values for the fields.

```
afTime = zeros(1,NumFrames-1);
for iFrameIter=1:NumFrames-1
    rgbCurrImage = read(hVideo,iFrameIter);
    rgbSubSampled = double(rgbCurrImage(1:2:end,1:2:end,:))/255;
    graySubSampled = 0.299*rgbSubSampled(:,:,1) + 0.587*rgbSubSampled(:,:,2) + 0.114*rgbSubSampled(:,:,3);
```

I think Python has a shorter way to do it (not manually for each channel) but just can't reach the same values in Matlab and Python. have been using cv2 for the reading of the video

this is my python code:

```
afSimilarity = np.zeros(number_of_frames - 1)
PrevResult = np.zeros(int(iQuantizedNumBlocks))

    for iFrameIter in range(number_of_frames - 1):
        print(iFrameIter)
        ret, rgbCurrImage = cap.read()
        rgbSubSampled = np.double(rgbCurrImage[::2, ::2, :]) / 255
        graySubSampled = 0.299 * rgbSubSampled[:, :, 2] + 0.587 * rgbSubSampled[:, :, 1] + 0.114 * rgbSubSampled[:, :, 0]
```

for example, for the first frame, the results I get in Python for the value of graySubSampled:
[image]

0.232776471 0.244988235 0.23174902  0.267937255

0.237278431 0.242094118 0.252003922 0.25592549

0.253478431 0.232976471 0.248215686 0.253545098

0.242094118 0.237278431 0.248215686 0.261388235

The values of rgbCurrImage in python are:
rgbCurrImage[0]:
67  55  65

68  56  66

71  58  68

73  60  70

IrgbCurrImage[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJtFo.png):
67  55  65

68  56  66

71  58  68

73  60  70

rgbCurrImage[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cn96I.png):
59  58  66

59  58  66

62  59  57

64  61  69

rgbCurrImage[3]:
60  59  67

60  59  67

61  58  66

63  60  68

I am prety sure that it is bgr and not rgb in python but I treated that after

and in Matlab:
[image]

0.239   0.251658824 0.241168627 0.277356863

0.242094118 0.246909804 0.258160784 0.262082353

0.2574  0.237345098 0.253031373 0.256058824

0.245121569 0.242607843 0.251243137 0.262113725

The values of rgbCurrImage in matlab are:
rgbcurrimage(1,:,:):
66  57  68

67  58  70

69  60  73

71  62  79

rgbcurrimage(2,:,:):
66  58  66

67  59  68

69  60  71

71  62  76

rgbcurrimage(3,:,:):
67  59  62

67  59  63

68  60  65

70  62  69

rgbcurrimage(4,:,:):
68  61  58

68  61  58

67  59  58

69  61  60

Comment: Where is your Python code?

Comment: @drops added it just now

Comment: Ok, what is the error message?

Comment: @drops there is no error message, I am saying that the values in for example "graySubSampled" are not the same for the same frame, in the python code and in the Matlab code. I also tried using video reader instead of video capture and still got different values

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example for that?

Comment: @drop added those too =)

Comment: Instead of images, rather give text. I cannot copy the numbers from the image. Also, instead of the output from your functions, i need the input, so i can reproduce the problem ;)

Comment: @drops I put the results in csv files, because they are matrixes of size 360X480, So I can't really copy them, and the source is a video file, in what way can I transfer all pf these to you?

Comment: you can also give only a minimal example of e.g. 3x3

Comment: Ok I added results in text 4X4

Comment: we need the input as text to reproduce your problem

Comment: @drops how do I provide that? I mean how do I get the first frame as a text? you mean the output of the function read?

Comment: rgbCurrImage(4,4,:)

Comment: @drops added those too, The weird thing is that they are not the same and I don't find the reason to the difference